# How to make a method that swaps mutable types? (Natural Numbers) Java

Tags: java, immutability, mutable

I don't know how the value of an object that is referring to a reference. I am not talking about integers by the way.

I want to make this method.

```
swapNN(NaturalNumber j, NaturalNumber n)
```

I want the references of `j` and `n` to be swapped but I don't get how it can be done when I am dealing inside of a method because of the limited scope.

Also how would I make a method that squared a mutable `NaturalNumber`?

Like this?

```
private static void square(NaturalNumber j)
```

Comment: Can u paste the structure of `NaturalNumber` class

Comment: Check this article. http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Answer (score 1):

> I want the references of j and n to be swapped

You cannot do that in Java since it is pass-by-value. One way to achieve this would be to have a wrapper class that holds the two references in two fields and swap those.

> Also how would I make a method that squared a mutable NaturalNumber?

That all depends on how the `NaturalNumber` is implemented. Multiply it with itself. Consider using a `BigInteger` or one of the bigger primitives so as to not overflow.

Comment: @Thilo Ooops, was thinking square root.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "swap" them cause the references (j,n) are passed by value - meaning, the "original" reference won't change.

That said, if NaturalNumber's content is mutable (meaning, none of its members is declared `final`) you can work around it by "copying" the content of them into each other (using a third NaturalNumber object like you do in "swap").

By "swapping the content" you'll have the same effect as "swapping" the references.

Comment: maybe you'll have the same effect. You could also get nasty side effects if there are other references pointing at the objects you are updating. Those will see the changes, too (which may or may not be what you want).

Comment: @Thilo - I believe that that's what you want if you're trying to do "swap" right ? ;)

Comment: It's not what "pass-by-reference" would do if Java had such a thing. That would only swap the two arguments to the method. Not any other references that may exist elsewhere in the program.

Comment: @Thilo what you're describing can be achieved by simply creating two new references and dumping the old ones. Doesn't sound like that's what he meant though...